# Best way to separate data from puppet code

Tags: puppet, theforeman

My site is storing some host specific info in foreman as smart variables.
I would like to consolidate all that info into readable puppet files and have version control over them.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Is "Hiera" a good solution?

[This article](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/the-problem-with-separating-data-from-puppet-code) is almost 3 years old. Has anything changed since then?

Comment: hiera is the only solution i have used to separate data from code. Works very well. I just glanced at that link briefly but it seems to be pretty accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article is still a state of the art analysis of the different approaches to handling configuration data. Even Puppet 4 will change little if anything about the general statements.